# Could not get Simulator application’s pid - Exit status: 70

Tags: ios, jenkins, xctest, xcodebuild, fastlane

When using Fastlane to test (Scan tool) an iOS project through Jenkins, I sometimes get the following error:

```
xcodebuild: error: Failed to build project X with scheme X.
Reason: Could not get Simulator application’s pid
Exit status: 70
```

Comment: Clean and build your project again. Some times it can be haooened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error occurs when the Mac executing xcodebuild/fastlane commands requires a password to be entered into a keychain tool popup.

I haven't found a way of dismissing this over SSH so physically attending the box, unlocking the computer and entering the password into the keychain works for me. A restart just after often helps too.